# xml file creation and export it using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

how can i write `<p> <br/> hello this is my creation </p>` in xml file while i am creating it by the use of asp.net .

it is showing

```
&lt;P&gt; text &lt;/P&gt;
```

pls some one help me to solve this

Comment: If you show us the code you're using we may be able to be more helpful

Answer (score 0):

Read this Question: [How do I un-escape XML entities easily in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201660/how-do-i-un-escape-xml-entities-easily-in-net)

Answer (score 0):

just write what evere the tags u want using innerxml Properties.

Like

```
node.innerxml=htmltags as string/html document
```